# SWT set max height of component inside ScrolledComposite

Tags: java, swt

I cannot figure out how to correctly set the height of my row composite.  I would like the following code snippet to display only one row of data. Any additional rows would be seen by using the scrollbar.  I have tried using rowContainer.setSize() but to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.

Please note that the scrolled composite is not directly linked to the rowContainer composite and contains other composites as well.

```
private void doStuff(final Composite parentContainer) {
    final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(
        parentContainer, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, 
        true, true));

    final Composite borderComposite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, 
        SWT.BORDER);
    borderComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    borderComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, 
        true));
    scrolledComposite.setContent(borderComposite);
    scrolledComposite.setSize(borderComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, 
        SWT.DEFAULT));

    // Create a container for a label and button
    final Composite labelAndAddButtonContainer = new Composite(
        borderComposite, SWT.NONE);
    labelAndAddButtonContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    labelAndAddButtonContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, 
        SWT.TOP, false, false));

    // Create a container to hold all dynamic rows
    final Composite rowContainer = new Composite(borderComposite, SWT.NONE);
    rowContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    rowContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false));

    // Create at least one row. 
    final Collection<String> rowData = getRowData();
    if (rowData.isEmpty()) {
        createRow(scrolledComposite, rowContainer, "");
    } else {
        for (final String text : rowData) {
            createRow(scrolledComposite, rowContainer, text);
        }
        // How do I adjust for the height so that only 1 row shows, 
        // and scrollbars appear if there is more than one row?
    }

    // Create a button
    final Button addButton = new Button(labelAndAddButtonContainer, 
        SWT.PUSH);
    addButton.setImage(someImage);

    final Label label = new Label(labelAndAddButtonContainer, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("SOME_LABEL");
}
```